How to Restrict mTLS Client Certificates to Specific Services Without Modifying Standard Software Verification Logic?
I’m setting up mTLS to secure communication between my application’s components, specifically Service A and Service B. I’ve issued server certificates for both Service A and Service B, and they trust the same root CA. I’ve also issued client certificates for my application to connect to these services.
The problem is that, because both Service A and Service B trust the same root CA, a client certificate intended for Service A can also authenticate to Service B, and vice versa. Unfortunately, I can’t modify the verification logic of Service A or Service B, and I want to avoid managing multiple intermediate CAs.
Is there a standard method in mTLS to ensure that a client certificate is only valid for a specific service (e.g., Service A only, Service B only) without altering the verification logic of the standard software? Any suggestions or best practices would be appreciated.
I set up a root and intermediate CA to issue server and client certificates for Service A and Service B in an mTLS setup. Both services trust the same root CA, but this allows a Service A client certificate to authenticate to Service B, which I want to prevent. I considered modifying the verification logic of Service A and Service B or using different intermediate CAs for each service, but both options add complexity or aren’t feasible.

You should not be manipulating the chain of trust to authorize a client certificate with a server. Instead, there are ways to configure the server to accept only certain certificates based on attributes of the client certificate, e.g. the subject name or SAN. How this is done depends on the web server. For example, in IIS you can configure client cert mapping authentication.

Yes, some specialized software supports configuring additional checks like the one you mentioned. However, this doesn’t seem to be a common feature. I attempted to use certificate policies and custom key usages with different OIDs per service but encountered issues in both OpenSSL (as shown in the following test) and Go’s built-in TLS library. Upon reviewing Go’s behavior regarding client certificate verification, I found that it only checks whether the client certificate has the clientAuth key usage and verifies the trust chain, with no additional checks.

openssl s_server -accept 4321 -cert srv1.pem -key srv1-key.pem -CAfile ca.pem -Verify 2 -verify_return_error

openssl s_client -cert cl2.pem -key cl2-key.pem -CAfile ca.pem -connect localhost:4321 -verify 2 -verify_return_error
